# Partialy no color for Symfony CLI in PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Symfony CLI in PhpStorm don't output all the colored character, but it works nice in Visual Studio Code.

It also works in Windows terminal but not in cmd console nor in PowerShell.

In Visual Studio Code:

[image: interactive CLI output in Visual Studio Code]

In PhpStorm:

[image: interactive CLI output in PhpStorm]

I'm working on Windows 10 ver 1903. And I don't have a clue of where the problem is...

Comment: *"It also works in Windows terminal but not in cmd console nor in PowerShell."* It should work better in ConEmu (at very least for cmd.exe sessions). Other than that: looks like recognizing ESC sequences that represent colors got broken at some point (and I have no clue where the issue might be). For me it's either works well (colors everywhere) or no colors at all (in plain cmd)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, PhpStorm doesn't support colored output in the Run tool window. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-46591

You get rid of those color codes by passing the `--no-ansi` parameter to the Symfony CLI script.